# Создание сайта или форума

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, (желательно на примере: я новичок в написании html-страниц, только начал учиться) на html-странице будущего сайта сделать форум или стену для записей. А также, если можно, как сделать форму ввода логина/пароля для входа на сайт (для администрирования). Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Тривиальный вопрос, ответ на который знает гугл: http://bit.ly/x4wpD2

Comment: данное сообщение как-то не тянет на "Ответ", можно было обойтись и комментом

Comment: Написание форума с нуля вряд ли себя оправдает. Ищи лучше готовые решения, благо есть из чего выбрать. Вопрос тривиальный, да))

Comment: А чем не угодил вордпресс? Я на нём отлично работаю.

Answer (score 2):

Что-бы создать форум или "Стену" тебе потребуются знания не только самых простых языков программирования таких как HTML и CSS, тебе требуются знания: JQuery, PHP, C++, JavaScript, а также никак без Баз данных MySQL

Comment: Ох, боюсь спросить, зачем для стены с++.

И не обязательно MySQL.


ЗЫ: HTML и CSS - не языки программирования.

Comment: С++ может и нет, но MySQL нужен, иначе как будут выводиться ники или нимена тех кто писал На Стенке/Форуме?

Comment: JQuery вовсе не обязательно, mysql это не единственное хранилище данных, OMFG. PHP, естественно, тоже т.к. сервер можно написать с использованием огромного количества платформ и языков.

Хотя кому я пишу... потребуются знания не только самых простых **языков программирования** таких как HTML и CSS.

Жестокий faic-palm :DDD

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не специалист в веб-дизайне и не профессиональный программист, не нужно тратить свое время на создание собственного скрипта или даже движка. Более того, не нужно пытаться установить на свой хостинг готовый скрипт вроде PunBB или PHPBB. Гораздо проще использовать готовый сервис, благо таких достаточно много. Например, [mybb.ru](http://mybb.ru) или [rusff.ru](http://rusff.ru). Обычно за небольшую мзду можно отключить рекламу, прикрутить форум к своему домену и т.д.

Comment: с готовым конструктором работать можно, но нет особого желания: легче намного, но хочется чего-то своего, отличного от других, даже если и похоже на чьё-то. Там не выйдешь за предоставленные сервисом и строго ограниченные рамки. А у меня цель- НАУЧИТЬСЯ делать самому.

Comment: Если цель научиться - вопрос должен выглядеть абсолютно по другому

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlbook.ru/html
Думаю вам пригодится=)

Если возникает вопрос как сделать форму логина/пароля, то советую почитать книги какиенибудь (RTFM! как говорится=) ). Вопрос простейший.

Answer (score 0):

Скачай простую гостевую книгу и посмотри исходники!:) Что бы встроить это к себе на PHP страницу, достаточно выполнить include.
Я, со своими маленькими знаниями, написал свою простую гостевую книгу (PHP):
http://narod.ru/disk/41065977001/gb.rar.html
Ты можешь посмотреть исходные коды — там нет ничего не понятного, так как я это делал когда "совсем" ничего не знал. Там нет использования MySQL и других подобных вещей, а только файлы :D.
Думаю, что это тебе поможет сделать стену, или форум, вот. :)

А что бы сделать форму входа, то не обязательно использовать форму. Можно устроить обычную проверку IP, а если это не подходит, то на хабрахабре есть отличная статья о авторизации на PHP + MySQL:
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/13726/

Comment: Угу, только забыл добавить - "сделать стену Васи Пупкина"

Comment: Нет же. Можно взять за основу

Comment: Вытянуть кусок-другой, посмотреть как работает и сделать своё

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы создать свой сайт/блог/все_что_хочешь_в_WEBе тебе потребуются знания языков программирования:
1) HTML и CSS, javascript (j-Qvery) для оформления внешнего вида
2) серверный язык программирования, например php (ruby, scala, haskell)
3) знания SQL для работы с базами данных, где будет хранится информация 
это минимум

Comment: Например для ruby, точнее его фреймворка Ruby on Rails (RoR) можно и не знать  SQL, там работа с базой может происходить благодаря синтаксису RoR